# Gryffindors have never gone so long without winning

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> Gryffindors have never gone so long without winning

I don't know the meaning of that sentence. 
I searched "never do without doing". 
That means you should do something, but I can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

It is an idiom: [to go without (something)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20without). Try searching for **go** without, not **do** without.

Examples:

> A week is a long time to go without eating.
>
> I have never gone so long without eating.
>
> How long can someone go without water?

Your sentence means, "Gryffindors have been losing for a long time: their longest time ever."

Comment: Sorry. I can't understand. I think double negative means postive. So I think Gryffindors have never gone so long without winning means Gryffindors have gone so long with winning.

Comment: Yes, in most sentences a double negative means a positive. BUT... "*to go without*" is an idiom. An idiom is defined as "a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words." For example, I sometimes say, " I was over the moon". It means I was delighted. I was NOT literally over the moon!  So your sentence has no double negative! It has one negative (never) and one *idiom* (to go without). "Without" is part of the idiom, and as I said, the meaning of an idiom cannot be deduced from the meanings of the individual words.

Comment: Please read my original answer carefully. I have told you what the sentence means. Your own meaning is wrong. The meaning I gave you is correct. I will try again. . . "For the longest period ever, Gryffindors have lost every match they've played." A more conversational version would be "Gryffindors haven't won a match for ages", but this doesn't mention that their failure has lasted an unprecedentedly long period of time.

Comment: Thank you! I read your comment again and understood it.

Comment: @user104857 I'm so glad! Good! Thanks for letting me know. By the way, welcome to English Language Learners!